# Hibernate evict vs flush with object which has no id

Tags: hibernate, session

Am trying to understand what happens if we create new user instance of entity User which doesnt have an id is used in hibernate session.flush(user) or session.evict(user), considering user instance has firstname, lastname etc values

Answer (score 1):

If you create instance of an entity and call either session.flush() or session.evict(user), the instance will not persisted i.e will not be written to database.

Now the question is what if you have made the instance Persistent?(by calling save(), saveOrUpdate(), persist() or merge()). In order to persist a instance, it's Primary Key i.e id must be set. If you have applied '**auto increment**' in table for id, then only instance will be saved otherwise you will get exception `java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`

We assume id is made 'auto increment' and entity is Persisted. Calling session.flush() will write to database explicitly( normally Hibernate writes to database at end of session to avoid multiple db hits).

Calling session.evict(Object) will make that instance Detached. Entry will be made to database after session is closed or session is flushed manually. Modification made to instance after calling evict() will not be written to database.

> Detached - a detached instance is an object that has been persistent, but its Session has been closed. The reference to the object is still valid, of course, and the detached instance might even be modified in this state. A detached instance can be reattached to a new Session at a later point in time, making it (and all the modifications) persistent again. This feature enables a programming model for long running units of work that require user think-time. We call them application transactions, i.e., a unit of work from the point of view of the user.

[Session#evict(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict(java.lang.Object))

> Remove this instance from the session cache. Changes to the instance will not be synchronized with the database. This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with cascade="evict".

session.evict() just changes state of object from Persistent-->Detached i.e entity is removed from session cache. Detached does not means that instance will be removed from database. To delete instance, you have to call delete() or remove().

[Session#flush](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush())

> Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent store with persistable state held in memory.